# Memory problems when running stanford nlp (stanford segmentator)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I downloaded the stanford segmentator and I am following the instructions but I am getting a memory error, the full message is here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.shapeOf(Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java:230)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.access$300(Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java:49)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter$CTBDocumentParser.apply(Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java:169)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter$CTBDocumentParser.apply(Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java:114)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.LineIterator.setNext(LineIterator.java:42)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.LineIterator.<init>(LineIterator.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.LineIterator$LineIteratorFactory.getIterator(LineIterator.java:108)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.wordseg.Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.getIterator(Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java:86)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.setNextObjectHelper(ObjectBank.java:435)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.setNextObject(ObjectBank.java:419)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.java:412)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:250)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ObjectBankWrapper.iterator(ObjectBankWrapper.java:45)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1193)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1137)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1091)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3023)
```

Before executing the file I tried increasing the heap space by doing `export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4000m`. I also tried splitting the file but still had the same error - I split the file to 8 chunks, so each had around 15MB each. What should I do to adjust the memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

The segment.sh script that ships with the segmenter limits the memory to 2G, which is probably the cause of the error.  Editing that file will hopefully fix the issue for you.